# Android Service producer-consumer implementation

Tags: android, service

I have an app which its main functionality is sending data to a server and receiving data from it.

Sending data is issued by the app's main activity, when user explicitly choose to do this, but the data receiving should be performed even if the app is destroyed, so when new data is received from the server, a notification will be launched, and also, the application's database will be updated so next time the application will be launched it could load this new data from database.

So, I have a service that take care of sending and reading from the server, and I want to know what is the best way you think for the following scenario;

If the service gets new data while the app's main activity is running, beside inserting it to the database I need this data to be received by the main activity and immediately present it to the user.

In a perfect world I would do that by keeping a reference of the activity inside the service, and when the service gets the data, it will call a method in the activity with it's reference.

But how should I implement this? should I use `Messenger`? should I store the data in the service in a `queue` and try to read this `queue` from the main activity?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by registering a broadcast receiver dynamically in the activity that has a reference to the activity that registered it. See the documentation for `Context.registerReceiver`. As for how to retrieve the data, depending on its size, I would either just include it in the Intent or only fire the Intent after putting the data in the database and include a reference to the inserted entry within the Intent.